# Rails: validates_presence_of attribute only if another attribute have specified value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models:

1. **type** — model with data types
2. **data** — model with data

Model **type**:

- `id` — key
- `name` — type name

Model **data**:

- `id` — key
- `type_id` — id of data type
- `main_value` — required data
- `opt_value` — optional data (it required only for specified data type)

How can I `validates_presence_of` `opt_value`, if I know that specified `type.name` exists and can't be changed?

I tried this method:

```
validates_presence_of :opt_value, :if => lambda { self.type_id == get_type_id }

def get_type_id
  Type.find_by(name: 'i_know_this_type_exists') # with and without .id
end
```

But it doesn't work. I think because I don't have access from `Data` model to `Type` model.

Though I may insert predefined data types within migration and know which `id` have specified data type, but I don't want to hardcode this `id` within validation `:if => lambda { self.type_id == 2 }` (even if it works).

How can I validate such cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

validates :opt_value, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new {|optvalue| optvalue.is_verified? }

```
   def is_verified?
     self.is_verified == "Verified"
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the special type logic should be resident in the Type class

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.special_type
    Type.find_by(name: 'i_know_this_type_exists').id
  end
end
```

Use Proc instead of lambda

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :opt_value, :if => Proc.new{|f| f.type_id == Type.special_type }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this suggestion from user **alexesDev** on another site. It works.

```
validates_presence_of :opt_value, if: :have_opt_value?

def have_opt_value?
  type_id == Type.select('id').where(name: 'some type').first
end
```